# Specify equality comparer for model binding to collection types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have an API where you can specify a list of names to get. Duplicate names are not allowed and if two names differ only by casing then they are considered duplicates.

```
GET /api/people?names=john&names=alice
```

In my own .NET code I would gather all these names in a `HashSet` with a custom equality comparer.

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

But I don't think ASP.NET Core model binding is flexible enough for that.

```
// GET /api/people?names=john&names=JOHN
[HttpGet("api/people")]
public GetPeople([FromQuery] HashSet<string> names)
{
    // this works but names contains both john and JOHN
}
```

What do I have to change so that the `names` set only contains john and not JOHN?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `List<string>` in the method header, and then load it into a HashSet according to your rules:

```
public GetPeople([FromQuery] List<string> names)
{
    var hashed = new HashSet<string>(names, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

As an alternative you could look into custom Model Binding, but it may only be worth the effort if you need it in multiple places.

Comment: I like this solution because it requires minimal effort but I would really like to let model-binding (or another framework feature) handle everything.

Comment: Please see the other answer that I just added.

Comment: Steven, check out my solution. It does work with model-binding without additional lines of code.

Comment: @PeterB funny we came to the same solution (I added my version right before you did)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashSet<string>` derivative that is set to always use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
// Case Insensitive String HashSet, or CIStringSet for short.
public class CIStringSet : HashSet<string>
{
    public CIStringSet() : base(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
    }
}
```

Using it is then very simple like this:

```
public object GetPeople([FromQuery] CIStringSet names)
{
    return Json(names);
}
```

Tested and it works:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a derived type that specifies the equality comparer and then bind to the derived type.

```
public class StringSetIgnoreCase : HashSet<string>
{
    public StringSetIgnoreCase()
        : base(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
// GET /api/people?names=john&names=JOHN&names=alice
[HttpGet("api/people")]
public GetPeople([FromQuery] StringSetIgnoreCase names)
{
    // names contains only john and alice
}
```

The issue with this solution is that it doesn't scale well: you have to create a derived type for every type of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A rather static solution with no error handling at all but what would work is the following

**Binder:**

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

    bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

    var values = valueProviderResult.Values.Select(value => value).ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(values);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test([ModelBinder(typeof(HashSetBinder))] IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        values
    });
}
```

then just open the url for instance like this:

*http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller?values=1&values=1&values=1&values=2*

result will be `{"values":["1","2"]}`

This could be registered globally with a [modelbinding-provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-model-binder-sample) but for that it would need to implement several more checks.